# MySQL join and store table with ON clause

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Trying to join two tables stored in database on a PID and storing the new table in a new table as below.

```
CREATE TABLE mod_table_INPUT_TARGET 
SELECT * 
FROM mod_table_DMRF 
INNER JOIN mod_table_2 
    ON mod_table_DMRF.tDMRF_ACE_ID = mod_table_2.t2_ACE_ID;
```

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'py_db.mod_table_INPUT_TARGET'
>   (errno: 139)

I don't understand the mysql error. All the columns have different names in both tables.

EDIT: I want to make a new table mod_table_INPUT_TARGET which is made by joining mod_table_2 and mod_table_DMRF, joined on the ACE_ID. I'm using innodb.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, can you explain?

Comment: @bluefeet: I think it's pretty clear what he's trying to do. He's trying to [create a new table based on the results of a query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html).

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to use `SELECT *` for this case. You know that at least one of your columns will always be an exact duplicate of another column. In the new table, `tDMRF_ACE_ID` will **always** hold the same value as `t2_ACE_ID`. Perhaps try explicitly listing the columns to be selected?

Comment: Please specify if you are using innodb or myisam

Comment: A quick google search for "mysql errno 139" finds results that talk about "max row size exceeded," so perhaps you can fix this by only selecting the columns you actually need, reducing the amount of data in each row.

Comment: it's innodb, platform is ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Traversty3, I really want all the columns if possible. Will try getting by with fewer for now.

Comment: Thanks so much Traversty3, I also found a useful shell function     perror, which said pretty much the the same thing for perror 139

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had too many columns which was blowing the row memory limit. Since cutting down to the most essential columns, I can run the statement.